# how to make the Cell in the react-big-calendar flexible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

how can i make the Cell of the react-big-calendar flexible depend on the how many events that we have and enable the scrolling .

here i will provide a screen shot to my issue
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're already using the [showAllEvents](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/docs/props--show-all-events) prop, to make the cell scrollable. This applies to all cells, and can not be controlled at an individual cell level.

RBC determines layout based on the overall height you've applied to the container element.